# Keras shape issue only when predicting

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

So I am at a loss here. I trained my model, everything works; But when I try to use the prediction method I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (64,) but got array with shape (1,)

Which I find very strange, since the input I am giving is (64,), I even returned the shape in cli like this

```
    print(type(test_x[0]))
    print(test_x[0].shape)
```

Which returns

> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
> (64,)

Which, in my mind, should work when I use

```
print(str(np.argmax(model.predict(test_x[0]))))
```

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Full error output:

> File "/home/drbunsen/Downloads/code/neural/random/neuralPlaying.py", line 115, in 
> main()
> File "/home/drbunsen/Downloads/code/neural/random/neuralPlaying.py", line 110, in main
> print(np.argmax(model.predict(train_x[0])))
> File "/home/drbunsen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1441, in predict
> x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
> File "/home/drbunsen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
> exception_prefix='input')
> File "/home/drbunsen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
> str(data_shape))
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (64,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model expects input shape as: `(number_of_samples,number_of_features)`.

If you want to pass 1 sample and each sample has 64 features, then shape of input should be like: `(1,64)`.
Since you have trained your model with 64 features, the input always should have `(N,64)` shape.

If you pass an array with shape `(64,)`, model considers it as 64 samples with 1 feature, which is incompatible with 64 expected features.

To resolve your issue pass input like:

```
print(str(np.argmax(model.predict(test_x[0].reshape(1,-1))))) # add first dimension
```